# Is an ordinary CD (like for music downloads) ok for downloading Ubuntu or do I need a DVD disc?

Tags: boot

I have music CDs, but not DVD discs. Can I use one of these CDs for downloading and installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS from a CD. Please see here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version you're downloading. Most CDs hold around 700MB, whereas the 12.04.4 release exceeds this capacity, as do all proceeding versions.

12.04.2 is the last version released below this limit, and can be found here:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/

Comment: Thanks for info. I decided to try Ubuntu on a trial basis and settled on version 13.10.  I have XP and so was instructed to download and install Infra Recorder and burn a DVD from it. However Norton Intenet Security identified Infra Recorder as an unsafe site and would not allow the download. So much for my getting Ubuntu!!